# PHP date formating problem with week number

Tags: php, date, formatting, date-formatting, php-carbon

I am providing my frontend with per-week report. I am receiving date interval and return data chunked by `W-Y` format (e.g 02-2018). The problem occures when I got for example 31.12.2018 as my interval's start date. When I am formatting that date with `W-Y` pattern, The result is 01-2018 because 31.12.2018 as week day "belongs to" 2019, so as week number formatter gives me 01, but as year a got 2018, which is  also true. But there is a problem because my chunkes must be continuous, but now my data looks like this:

```
{
  "01-2018": [...],
  "02-2019": [...],
  "03-2019": [...],
  .....
}
```

Any suggestions how to design all these ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `o` format for the year when you are using ISO week numbers. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> o: ISO-8601 year number. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)

```
echo (new DateTime('2018-12-31'))->format('W-o');
```

Output:

```
01-2019
```

Answer (score 1):

use date format W-o :)

> o:    ISO-8601 year number. This has the same value as Y, except that if
>   the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that
>   year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)